# Clasificar por atributo nodos seleccionados con xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Estoy scrapeando una web cuya información está en una tabla con la siguiente estructura.

```
<tbody>
   <tr class='Leaguestitle'>
      <td>...<\td>
      <td>...<\td>
   <\tr>
   <tr id='tr1_abababa'>
      <td>...<\td>
      <td>...<\td>
   <\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_abababa'>..<\tr>
    .
    .
   <tr id='tr1_acacaca'>..<\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_acacaca'>..<\tr>
   <tr align='center'>..<\tr>
    .
    .
   <tr id='tr1_cbcbcbc'>..<\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_cbcbcbc'>--<\tr>
<\tbody>
```

Esta estructura es periódica. A mi lo que me interesa es el nodo con atributo `class` que me da un encabezado, los nodos con atributo `id` que contengan tr1 y el nodo con atributo `align` que es el que marca el final de los datos que me interesan. Para ello, creo una lista con los 3 tipos de nodos haciendo esto:

```
allrows = table.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='Leaguestitle' or contains(@id,'tr1') and not (@align='center')]")
```

Mi deseo es iterar la lista, y en función de si el nodo es de atributo `class` que vaya a una sublista, si es de atributo `id` que vaya a otra, y si es el nodo con atributo `align` finalizar el programa.

El problema es que los nodos `tr` seleccionados no tienen la estructura del principio, es decir esta:

```
<tr id='tr1_abababa'>
  <td>...<\td>
  <td>...<\td>
<\tr>
```

Sino esta:

```
  <td>...<\td>
  <td>...<\td>
```

Por lo que al no estar presente el atributo `id` del nodo `tr`, ni el atributo `class` o el `align` me es imposible direccionar dicho nodo a una lista u otra.

¿Cómo podría, de una forma pythonica, realizar dicha clasificación?

Answer (score 0):

cuando iteras la lista "allrows" cada elemento es un WebElement y a un WebElement le puedes preguntar por alguna de sus propiedades con la funcion `getAttribute(name)` donde el name es el nombre del atributo. Por ejemplo:

```
for i in allrows:
    # i es un WebElement
    # i.getAttribute("class") deberia ser un String
    if i.getAttribute("class") == "Leaguestitle":
        titleList.append(i)
    elif:
    .
    .
    .
```

Usando `i.getAttribute("id")`.contains() y funciones de tratamiento de String podras clasificarlos en un unico bucle.

Otra opcion es que obtengas dos listas diferentes con dos `findelements` diferentes, de esa manera despues no tienes que clasificar, obtienes directamente las dos listas ya clasificadas.

```
leaguesTitlerows = table.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='Leaguestitle']")
tr1rows = table.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'tr1') and not (@align='center')]")
```